# Python/Pandas merge issue with NaN data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to use pd.concat to merge two data frames (*df* and *df2*) into one new dataframe (*df3*) in Pandas using the following code:

*df3 = pd.concat([df, df2])*

This almost works the way I want it to, but it creates an issue.

*df* contains data for the current date, and the index is a time series. It looks like this:

```
                        Facility    Servers   PUE
2016-10-31  00:00:00    6.0         5.0       1.2
2016-10-31  00:30:00    7.0         5.0       1.4
2016-10-31  01:00:00    6.0         5.0       1.2
2016-10-31  01:30:00    6.0         5.0       1.2
2016-10-31  02:00:00    6.0         5.0       1.2
```

*df2* contains NaN data only and the index is a time series that corresponds in format to the one in *df*, but beginning on an earlier date and continuing for a full year (i.e. 17520 rows to correspond to 365 * 48 thirty minute intervals). It looks basically like this:

```
                        Facility    Servers   PUE
2016-10-01  00:00:00    NaN         NaN       NaN
2016-10-01  00:30:00    NaN         NaN       NaN
2016-10-01  01:00:00    NaN         NaN       NaN
2016-10-01  01:30:00    NaN         NaN       NaN
2016-10-01  02:00:00    NaN         NaN       NaN
2016-10-01  02:30:00    NaN         NaN       NaN
<continues to 17520 rows, i.e. one year of 30 minute time intervals>
```

When I apply: *df3 = pd.concat([df, df2])*

and then run *df3.head()*, I get the following:

```
                        Facility    Servers   PUE
2016-10-31  00:00:00    6.0         5.0       1.2
2016-10-31  00:30:00    7.0         5.0       1.4
2016-10-31  01:00:00    6.0         5.0       1.2
2016-10-31  01:30:00    6.0         5.0       1.2
2016-10-31  02:00:00    6.0         5.0       1.2
2016-10-31  02:30:00    NaN         NaN       NaN
2016-10-31  03:00:00    NaN         NaN       NaN
2016-10-31  03:30:00    NaN         NaN       NaN
<continues to the end of the year>
```

In other words, the code seems to remove all of the NaN data for the time intervals that occurred before the data in *df*. Can anyone advise on how to preserve all of the data in *df2*, replacing it with data only for the corresponding time intervals from *df*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) by [`union`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.union.html) of both `indexes`:

```
print (df2.index.union(df.index))
DatetimeIndex(['2016-10-01 00:00:00', '2016-10-01 00:30:00',
               '2016-10-01 01:00:00', '2016-10-01 01:30:00',
               '2016-10-01 02:00:00', '2016-10-01 02:30:00',
               '2016-10-31 00:00:00', '2016-10-31 00:30:00',
               '2016-10-31 01:00:00', '2016-10-31 01:30:00',
               '2016-10-31 02:00:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)

df = df.reindex(df2.index.union(df.index))
print (df)
                     Facility  Servers  PUE
2016-10-01 00:00:00       NaN      NaN  NaN
2016-10-01 00:30:00       NaN      NaN  NaN
2016-10-01 01:00:00       NaN      NaN  NaN
2016-10-01 01:30:00       NaN      NaN  NaN
2016-10-01 02:00:00       NaN      NaN  NaN
2016-10-01 02:30:00       NaN      NaN  NaN
2016-10-31 00:00:00       6.0      5.0  1.2
2016-10-31 00:30:00       7.0      5.0  1.4
2016-10-31 01:00:00       6.0      5.0  1.2
2016-10-31 01:30:00       6.0      5.0  1.2
2016-10-31 02:00:00       6.0      5.0  1.2
```

Comment: Thanks. Exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

use **combine_first**

```
result = df1.combine_first(df2)
```

result will only takes values from the right DataFrame if they are missing in the left DataFrame

Comment: Thank you for this.